# "Ärgerlich" vs "verärgert"

Tags: word-usage

Im Heft *Deutsch Perfekt* steht folgender Satz:

> Auch die Armeechefs sind sehr **ärgerlich** über das "unerlaubte
>   Fraternisieren".

Ich habe das Adjektiv *ärgerlich* immer in der Struktur *etwas ist ärgerlich / man findet etw. ärgerlich* gehört und nicht *jemand **ist** ärgerlich*. [DUDEN](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aergerlich) gibt beides an:

- sie ist ärgerlich auf/über mich, über den Misserfolg
- es ist sehr ärgerlich, dass wir uns verpasst haben.

Viel öfter habe ich *etw. ärgert mich* oder *ich bin verärgert* gehört. Würdet Ihr, Muttersprachler, tatsächlich *ich bin ärgerlich über etw.* sagen? Wenn inhaltlich beide (*ärgerlich* und *verärgert*) synonym sind, gibt es vielleicht einen stilistischen Unterschied?

Comment: Ehrlich gesagt, nein. Ich war kurz davor, zu lamentieren, dass da jemand ein Lehrbuch geschrieben hat, ohne die Sprache zu kennen :) Jetzt ärgert mich  natürlich sehr, dass der DUDEN mehr weiß als ich :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen   Ja, das ist ärgerlich.

Answer (score 3):

Persönlich würde Ich eher zu "Ich bin wütend" oder "Ich bin verärgert" tendieren.

Umgangssprachlich würde man im Deutschen "Ich bin ärgerlich" normalerweise nicht verwenden.

Im normalen Sprachgebrauch wird "ärgerlich" im Kontext "Etwas ist ärgerlich" verwendet.

Comment: Ich würde es anders formulieren: "Er bin ärgerlich über..." würde ich *allenfalls* in der Umgangssprache (mündlich) anzutreffen vermuten. In etwas gewählterer Ausdrucksweise (schriftlich) würde man dagegen "Er ist verärgert über..." sagen. Also: ein stilistischer Unterschied. Es kann überdies noch gut sein, dass die Verwendung von *ärgerlich sein über* regional unterschiedlich ist.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ichbin Erbin. "... ALS in der Umgangssprache anzutr. verm.?" Überregional?

Comment: @userunknown  Öh... ja, das war ein Tüppfähler. Muss natürlich "Er ist ärgerlich..." heißen.

Answer (score 2):

*Ärgerlich* ist etwas speziell, weil es (zumindest historisch) beide Deutungen zulässt. Häufiger ist, wie bei *erstaunlich*/*erstaunt*, dass das Adjektiv auf *-lich* einen möglichen Auslöser für etwas beschreibt, (also "kann Anlass zu Erstaunen geben"), während *erstaunt* nur sich für die Empfängerseite des Erstaunens eignet.